# IP tables on VPS

Tags: centos, ip, firewall, iptables, vps

I am trying to setup iptables on a GoDaddy Virtual Host using the following:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -L -v

## open port ssh tcp port 22 ##
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

## open tcp port 25 (smtp) for all ##
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

## open dns server ports for all ##
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

## open http/https (Apache) server port to all ##
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

## open tcp port 110 (pop3) for all ##
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT

## open tcp port 143 (imap) for all ##
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
```

Every time I start the iptables service, none of the websites on this server are functioning and I cant access Plesk.

If I service iptables stop, it all works again. Is there a simple syntax error here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `/etc/init.d/iptables save` to save your rules?  If you are on CentOS 6 you will need to run `yum install policycoreutils` prior to `/etc/init.d/iptables save` or you will get an error.  Once you save the rules you need to restart iptables.

Also, you need to add a rule for port 8443 to be able to get to Plesk.